# How do you customize command line in Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am wondering how you can customize the argument command line in java to omit calculations in IntelliJ community edition. The book I have used for instructions only applies to NetBeans, which I am unable to access as of now. The following code attempts to do this:

```
public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    float sum  = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

            sum = sum + Float.parseFloat(args[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Those numbers add up to " + sum);
      }
}
```

It's expected I have direct access to configuring the main string argument,  I can enter in 8 6 7 5 3 0 9.

The intended output after running this program would look something like this:

"Those numbers add up to 38.0"

[1]: http://workbench.cadenhead.org/book/java-7-24 hours/source/chapter18/Calculator.java

Answer (score 2):

Use Run/Debug Configurations | **Program arguments** in [Application Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-application.html):
[image]